# Laravel date time is UTC, while locale is set to Europe/Brussels using Carbon

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I want to get all my dates and time into the locale `Europe/Brussels`. Now the problem I have here is that my `config/app.php` the timezone here is set to `Europ/Brussels`. Also in `App/filters.php`, I have this peace of code:

```
ini_set("date.timezone", "Europe/Brussels");
```

Just to make sure the timezone IS `Europ/Brussels`.

However, when I post something into the database, it is UTC format and when I get et out of the database it also is UTC.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong?

And how this is possible?

Can someone tell me, if you need something, or so? Because, I can't find the issue that causes this.

I need to say, the production enviroment has this, but the development not?

Comment: just to be sure check the output of timezone using: `var_dump(Config::get('app.timezone'));`

Comment: I just get `string(15) "Europe/Brussels"`, So I don't see what's wrong...

Comment: inside `config` have you got any folder called as `env` or `envinornment` or `local`

Comment: Yes, I do? Why? You can't set anything inthere right?

Comment: Are you expecting that all the dates are automatically converted after you're done querying the database or what? To me, it doesn't appear there's any problem here.. How are you displaying these dates that you say are "wrong"?

Comment: @NishanthMatha It's called local. @Mjh They are being stored UTC and I get them via a Query and display them with Carbon like `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime)->format('d-m-Y')`.

Comment: in that folder if you got `app.php` try setting `timezone => 'Europ/Brussels'` to me it seems somewhere in your local config you are overriding the timezone

Comment: Note that 's spelled `Europe` not `Europ`

Comment: It has the same result. Nothing changed. So the time now needs to be 17:xx ad what I get is 15:xx.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to *tell* Carbon which time zone you wish to coerce the date to? It's the 3rd parameter for the function `createFromFormat`.

Comment: I guess you can set it globally? Bot where and how?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive your mysql time zone is wrong.

Edit `my.cnf` and set

```
default_time_zone='Europe/Brussels'
```

Restart mysql server

Comment: `show variables like '%time_zone%';` Execute this query and paste me the result.

Comment: Yeah, the question is, how? I don't have acces as root to the SQL server?

Comment: See my answer. If you don't have server access, ask your hosting provider.